# Looping a loop with slight change - opening folders and files, and then do the same loop again but open files from next folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and would appreciate some help. I don't think it's that difficult, it's just that my knowledge limits me!

I have created this following sub to open files containing *100 in folder "beamresult\1", and it works great.
However, my challenge is, I have 12 different folders that I wish to open files from.
Plus, in those folders I'd like to open the different files *100, *200, ..., *900.

So in a way I would like to loop this sub, from folder 1 to 12. And in all those folders open all the files and edit them.

(In the full sub there is lots of code before 'loop' to edit my file, but the same editing should be done for all the documents.)

Hope that someone has a smart idea how to fix this!

```
Sub OpenFiles()
'opens all files in a folder
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

MyFolder = "C:\Beamresults\1"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*100.xls")

Do While MyFile <> ""

Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

MyFile = Dir

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Are all folders within the same higher level folder?  If so, a recursive function would be the simplest solution for 'walking' through all sub folders looking for files with *??? and processing them.

Comment: Yes all folders, 1-12, are in the same folder. A recursive function would probably work. How does one of those look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub OpenFiles()

    'opens all files in a folder
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim x as Long

    For x = 1 to 12
        MyFolder = "C:\Beamresults\" & x
        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*" & x & "00.xls")

        Do While MyFile <> ""

            Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
            'process and close file

            MyFile = Dir

        Loop
   Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: That works great Tim! As i said, simple solution.But I have one more question. Later on my files will not be named as simple as *100 and so on(this was just a testrun). They will be called different; TopChord, Post, TopChod_P, TopChord_DP and some other with a total of 7 different names. How to solve that mystery?

Is it possible to make a string or array or something like that for all of those names and go through all of them?